# Remove a list in a list of lists based on condition

Tags: python

I have the following list of lists:

```
lst = [['a',102, True],['b',None, False], ['c',100, False]]
```

I'd like to remove any lists where the value in the second position is None. How can I do this (in a list comprehension)

I've tried a few different list comprehension but can't seem to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `lst` is a tuple with nested tuples, you'll need to confirm if they are lists or tuples.

Comment: Tuples are immutable. It's impossible to remove an element of a tuple. Now, you can iterate over the tuple and create a new tuple with the desired values filtered out.

Comment: @MichaelM. I rolled back. It's not up to us to decide which part of the question is right and which part is wrong. (I.e., whether they have lists or tuples.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
lst = (('a',102, True),('b',None, False), ('c',100, False))
lst = tuple([el for el in lst if el[1] is not None])
print(lst)  # => (('a', 102, True), ('c', 100, False))
```

Your data is a tuple of tuples, not a list of lists, so you need to convert it to a tuple at the end.

Comment: OP's question and expected output is unclear

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Oops, sorry. I've updated my answer.

Comment: No need to use a list comprehension. You can pass a generator expression to `tuple`. `lst = tuple(el for el in lst if el[1] is not None)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lst = [item for item in lst if item[1] is not None]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` and `lambda` to generate new tuple if lement in index 1 (second position) of inner tuple not equals `None`:

```
lst = tuple(filter(lambda i: i[1] != None, lst))

# (('a', 102, True), ('c', 100, False))
```